# How do I resize/crop images simualar to how background-size:cover does?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

I am building a responsive site using bootstrap 3 & I need a photo gallery on it. The client want to update the gallery themselves..

My issue is the images that they upload can be of any size & any proportion.. How can I make the image fit a certain size div?

Requirements (must work similar to background-size:cover):

-images must keep their original proportions (can be cropped to fit the div)

-images must be stretched/shrunk to fit the FULL div (no white space)

-image must be centered vertically & horizontally in the div

I know I can do something like this but I need it to work more like "background-size:cover":

```
.myImages {
height:300px;
width:300px;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w4xTN/1/

**EXAMPLE:**

You can see at the link below that I have used "background-image:cover" for the "featured properties" photos.. I need to do something similar for normal images (unless someone knows of an image gallery that will support "background-image:cover" for the images?):

http://new.amberlee.com.au/for-sale/browse-for-sales

NOTE: JQuery/Javasript is OK to use & resizing them on upload is not an option ;)

Answer (score 0):

You've got your  tag within the .myImages  so you need to add properties for your  tag hence:

```
.myImages > img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

If you want to center the img, just change the height or width attribute to "auto";

you could also hack the img tag to center vertically whereby the image is cropped with playing with the vertical margin: 
e.g.

```
 margin-top: -33%;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/denistsoi/rLmxL/1/

Answer (score 0):

**No**, you can't get it quite like `background-size:cover` **but..**

This approach is pretty damn close: it uses javascript to determine if the image is long or tall and applies styles acordingly.

JS

```
    $('.myImages img').load(function () {
    var height = $(this).height();
    var width = $(this).width();
    console.log('widthandheight:', width, height);
    if (width > height) {
        $(this).addClass('wide-img');
    }
    else {
        $(this).addClass('tall-img');
    }
});
```

CSS

```
.tall-img{
    margin-top:-50%;
    width:100%;
}
.wide-img{
    margin-left:-50%;
    height:100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b3PbT/

Edit: this is a shameless repost from your last question ;)